# A date format that isn't picked up by Google as keyword

Tags: seo, date-format

My site is lacking a bit of written content through reasons I cannot control, but it does feature a lot of dates. Currently my top keyword is "Jul" because my date format is like this:

> 10th of Jul

Within the Google Webmaster page it lists my highest keywords. I was wondering, if I put my dates in a specific format, will it know that they are dates and therefore exclude them as a keyword, in the same way that it seems to do for words like "the, of" etc.

Comment: Every word is a keyword. I wouldn't be worrying about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> […] if I put my dates in a specific format, will it know that they are dates and therefore exclude them as a keyword […]

I'm almost 100% sure it won't exclude them as keywords. I guess indefinite and definite articles, prepositions and such are much easier for a search algorithm to discount without erroneous results than are day or month names.

I suppose you could do a little experiment and try marking up publish dates with HTML5 `<time>` element, `pubdate` attribute, etc., and see if that does anything. I *suspect* it won't now, but might do in the future.